# Links in extension pop-up and event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, preventdefault

I am working on a Chrome extension in which upon clicking some links inside the extension pop-up, divs are hidden or shown in the same pop-up via jQuery. An example could be:

```
 // user clicks on link in pop-up
 $("#footer .suggest-improvements").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $suggestion = $('#suggestion'), // suggestion form div in pop-up
      $content = $('#content'); // main content div in pop-up

  $content.fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $suggestion.show();
  });
});
```

The problem is that even though I have included the event.preventDefault() statement, whenever I click on the link, the extension tries to open a new page in the browser window which obviously is what I am trying to avoid.

I could use a <span> instead of an <a> element and it would work just fine, but now I am curious about this and I guess I need to know it for the future. What is the correct way of preventing the extension from opening a page in the main window when a user clicks on a link inside the extension pop-up?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, you're clicking on some `<a class="suggest-improvements" ...>` element? (i.e., the class being selected by jQuery is directly on the `a` element) Also, just to be sure, you're certain that the elements exist at the time the selection takes place (e.g., if you do `$("#footer .suggest-improvements").css("background-color", "red")` or change from `click` to `mouseover`, that happens successfully)

Comment: Yes, the element is a `<a class="suggest-improvements" ...>` and all the other `div` exist when the code is ran. In fact if I forget about transforming other elements and just do something simple as adding a simple string after the link (`event.preventDefault();$(this).after('foo');`) it still doesn't work and the extension tries to open a new page in the main window.

Comment: Can you add the relevant chunk of the HTML code to the question?